# Can you rearrange the order of Kronecker deltas?

Tags: tensor-products

I'm gunna give this one more try and see if anything good happens.

Suppose one has $$\delta_{ij} \delta_{lm} \delta_{kj}$$
Could one then rearrange the order to make 
$$\delta_{ij} \delta_{kj} \delta_{lm} ?$$

Furthermore, can the order of the indices change like with the levi-civita operator to make

$$\delta_{ij} \delta_{jk} \delta_{lm} $$ (notice the j and k switched places in the middle term) which would then allow this to simplify?

Comment: You should write down the definition of your delta function and check if you have equality.

Comment: Doesn't matter what I write down, because matrix multiplication isn't commutative, I'm not going to trust some random violation of its axioms. If you have an actual answer that would actually help 100s of people for when they google this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: there is  a likely simple answer, but context is everything. You had best type in a  complete expression that contains this, with special attention to which index variables are summed.

Comment: Or you could have given answer. No thanks to anyone here, I found an answer myself by inference of a theorem relating to determinants, but lets see if you can actually make a post that is beneficial to people instead of wasting their time.